# create a dynamic template and binding the content angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-directive

following these great article [link](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/comment-page-1/#comment-7227) i have write my own directive to dinamically create a template for a window that have to be characterized by the nature of the data that will have to send, to be more clear my app have to send a text input, the directive creates a input area, rather then a checkbox in the case that have to send a boolean.
After succesfully obtain the directive i have found a problem in binding the contents of templates to send it back.
I have read the documentation of the [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), and i find the transclude value that maybe can help me, but i didn't have success in my attempt, i write the code below, like they ara in my app

## HTML

```
<div id="notespace">
    <div id="userContainer" >
        <template-type content="additionalField">
                {{toBind}}
        </template-type>
        <button ng-click="addNote(toBind)">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

## JSfile of HTML controller page

```
var noteCtrl = function ($scope) {   
        $scope.additionalField=[{
             template:'text'
             }]

        for(var counter=0;counter<$scope.additionalField.length;counter++){
            var template;
            switch ($scope.additionaField[counter].template) {
                case 'text':
                    template = 'inputNote';
                    break;
                case 'otherTypeOfText':
                    template = 'areaNote';
                    break;
                case 'number':
                    template = 'inputNote';
                    break;                   
                case 'bool':
                    template = 'checkNote';
                    break;
                case 'file':
                    template = 'fileNote';
                    break;
            }
        }
    })
$scope.addNote=function(a) {
    alert(a);
}
```

## JSfile for the DIRECTIVE

```
templateApp.directive('templateType',function($compile){
    var inputNote='<div><input type="text"/></div>';
    var areaNote='<div><textarea ></textarea></div>';
    var checkNote='<div><input type="checkbox" /></div>';
    var fileNote='<div >file</div>';

    var getTemplate=function(type){
        var template='';
        switch (type) {
            case 'inputNote':
                template = inputNote;
                break;
            case 'areaNote':
                template = areaNote;
                break;
            case 'checkNote':
                template = checkNote;
                break;
            case 'fileNote':
                template = fileNote;
                break;
        }
        return template;
    };
    var linker=function(scope,element,attrs){

        element.html(getTemplate(scope.content.template));
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };
    return{
        restrict:"E",
        replace:true,
        transclude:true,
        link:linker,
        scope:{
            content:'='
        }
    };
});
```

to be extremelly clear the problem is that the addNote function's alert print nothing or undefined and not the content of the template like the inputArea one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the value you sent inside the directive, just add the `ng-transclude` directive to the element in which you want to copy the interpolated value of the expression `toBind`.

```
app.directive('foobar', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: ...
    }
}])
```

Usage:

```
<foobar>{{someValueFromScope}}</foobar>
```

Result:

```
<div>someValueFromScope</div>
```

**EDIT:**

If I understood your problem now, you could do something like this:

`<template-type content="additionalField" option="toBind"></template-type>`

In directive:

```
var inputNote='<div><input type="text" ng-model="option"/></div>';

scope: {
    content: '=',
    option: '@'
}
```

Now when you change the content of the input it will be reflected in the `option` variable.

**EDIT 2:**

I got a working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5YZK/)

I also corrected the code in the previous edit.

**EDIT 3:**
When you change the value of `options`, the directive broadcasts an event `optionsValueChanged` to its parent scope (which happens to be the scope of the controller). The scope reacts to this event by updating the value of `data.anotherValue`. But it's not really the way these things should be handled, if you really need to use a value in more than one place then it's better to use a `provider` (`value` or `service`). It's not really relevant/useful to your question.

Comment: yes in that way i can pass the {{someValueFromScope}} of the div, but if instead of a div i have an input, hoW can i pass the content that the user write? because it seems that ng-model doesn't work in this logic

Comment: no for some reason it still doesn't work, i'll do a plunker,if you want we can work one sec on it

Comment: Of course, maybe also someone also will look into it if you link it here.

Comment: Check my second edit, I have a working example for you.

Comment: you're like a genius, i had noted the code error while i'm trying to re-write the plunker, but you have beat me in time and bring the solution great work!

Comment: No genius, just a lot of time struggling before you :) feel free to ask if there is something missing.

Comment: only one question on the optionChangeEvent, about about it works, i don't completely understand it

Comment: Added explanation in the answer.

Comment: hi excuse me if i disturb you again, but i have insert a ng-change in the templates, and i need to override it in the controller is it possible? the jsFiddle is already updated take a look

Comment: I don't see the update in the fiddle, try to edit your question and link it there. It is probably possible to do what you want, but if it's not strictly related to this question you should open a new one!

Answer (score 0):

In Html you should add controller something like this

```
<div id="notespace" ng-controller="noteCtrl">
    <div id="userContainer" >
        <template-type content="additionalField">
                {{toBind}}
        </template-type>
        <button ng-click="addNote(toBind)">CONFERMA</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the controller is allready i it, i repeat everything goes ok, except the fact that i cannot bind the input fields value to the scope